# Merge two SQL queries together (syntax issue)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, timestampdiff

I'm using PHP to send this query where `lastConn` is a `datetime` object.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, lastConn FROM users LIMIT $startIndex, 50") or die($mysqli->error);
```

However my goal is not to get the raw `lastConn` data, but the time difference between `lastConn` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I wrote this query which does the job :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,lastConn,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS 'duration' FROM users;
```

I'm now trying to merge these two queries together to get the time difference in the first query but I can't seem to find the correct syntax.

Here is how I'm retrieving the data after performing the query using PHP:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['username'];
    echo $row['lastConn']; //should echo the time difference instead of the raw lastConn value
}
```

How can I directly get the time difference between lastConn and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in my first query, without having to use a second one ?

Comment: and you did try: 
    $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, lastConn, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,lastConn,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS 'duration' FROM users LIMIT $startIndex, 50")

Comment: *facepalm* I didn't think I could do it this way although it seems perfectly obvious now that I see it... I need to brush up on my SQL. Can you post your answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could probably just add the portion of your second query to the first, like this below. you had it all working, just needed that last step!

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, lastConn, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,lastConn,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS 'duration' FROM users LIMIT $startIndex, 50")
```

hope this helps.